# Calculate ratio based on median of two groups

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to calculate a ratio of median female salaries to median male salaries (the salary field is called Bscmpnstntotal). I think I need something like the following, but it is producing a syntax error:

```
=IF (ATTR([Gender]="female") THEN WINDOW_MEDIAN([Bscmpnstntotal]) ELSE 0 END / IF (ATTR([Gender]="male") THEN WINDOW_MEDIAN([Bscmpnstntotal]) ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using WINDOW_MEDIAN? That's a table calc function which means it operates on the table of aggregated query results instead of on the original data rows in the data source. You can *optionally* provide offsets to operate on a specific slice of the window of table results.

For example, WINDOW_MEDIAN(SUM(Profit), -2,0)

This takes the median of summing profit from the current to the two previous rows

You're getting a syntax error because you're returning an aggregate in the IF and a single value, 0. It would avoid that syntax error if you changed it to something like:

```
MEDIAN(IF [gender] = 'Male' THEN [Bscmpnstntotal] ELSE 0 END)
```

However don't do this:

A safer approach would be to get the Bscmpnstntotal isolated. The reason being that you want the median calculated only for the female entries, and not be skewed by the 0s for when we don't have female, the males.

So create a calc field like this:

```
MEDIAN(IF [Gender]="female" THEN [Bscmpnstntotal] END)
```

Do the same for males

Then have a calc field like this:

[female median]/[male median]